# completion handler in method which request information from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, objective-c-blocks

I have a method which send request to server and i have created the call to that function with completionHandler as follows:

```
-(void)sendAddSubscriptionRequest:(NSString*)owner withComppletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL, NSArray *, NSError *))completion
   dataWebService = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSURL* aUrl = [NSURL
                   URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/add?"]];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request =
    [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                        timeoutInterval:30.0];        
    [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", "token"]
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString* postData =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"owner=%@",
     owner];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];        
    NSData* returnData = [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    };
```

My problem is how should i return completion handler to my function after the data is fetched.

Thanks,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are sending an asynchronous request, the method will return immediately as the data will be "returned" in the `NSURLConnection` completion handler.  You can then decode it there and pass it along to your own completion handler:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:nil
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSArray *array = nil;
    if (!connectionError)
        array = /* get from data somehow */
    completion(!connectionError, array, connectionError);
}];
```

Note: It's not clear what your completion handler parameters mean, so I might have taken some liberties.